# dynamic selected value in drop down list

Tags: php, list, select, dynamic

i have a drop down list in a kohana view, in a for loop. it looks like that:

```
<? for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++):?>                        
    <option <?= $content->product_type->stock_2 == $i ? 'selected="selected"' :'';?> value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i; ?></option>
<? endfor; ?>
```

My problem is that i want to have selected a dynamically value, $content->number , always, in my list. How can i make that ? it is a little thing that i don't see. i tried 'selected="selected"' :'$content->number' , but doesn;t work...

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? You select that option which number is in `$content->product_type->stock_2`. Maybe you want `$content->number == $i` ? In your code, you are adding the number to the HTML instead of `selected="selected"` if it is *not* selected, which generates invalid HTML.

Comment: @Gaurav: Negative; it is not required.

Comment: i can select numbers in the interval 1-6. but i come from another page in which a selection has already been made. so i want the user to see default that particular value, $content->number by default. in the list. that;s all . i just want in that list the value $content->number to be default.in that list. i mention that this value is visible in the php pagem there is no prob with that.

Comment: that $content->product_type->stock_2 is a limitation. one canot choose more than it is already in the stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one cannot choose more than `$content->product_type->stock_2`, then shouldn't you iterate until that number instead of selecting it?

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $content->product_type->stock_2; $i++): ?>                        
    <option <?php echo ($content->number == $i ? 'selected="selected"' :''); ?> 
            value="<?php echo $i ?>">
                <?php echo $i; ?>
    </option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well Sorry for the misleading answer, But this is working on plain php so something must be amiss with the content.

```
<?php

$max=10; 
$content->product_type->stock_2 = 2;

?>


<select>
<? for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++):?>                        
    <option <?= $content->product_type->stock_2 == $i ? 
         'selected="selected"' :'';?> value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i; ?></option>
<? endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it right. I have made a few minor syntax enhancements.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++):
    ?>
    <option <?php if ($i == $content->product_type->stock_2) echo 'selected="selected"' ?> value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php
endfor;
?>
```

If this is not what you meant, please provide more information as to why you think it's "not working".

Comment: still the same. i just want that value $content->number to be selected. that's all. that value is perfectly 'visible' on page, and is a number. i want it to be selected by default.

Comment: Yes, we got that. Why do you keep saying `$content->number` when it's `$content->product_type->stock_2`? This is the correct code, so something else is wrong. If you're using Firefox, be aware that when you refresh the page, your previous selection is used.. not the HTML `selected` value. Try loading the page from scratch when you test.

Comment: content->number is different from sale stock. The first is the number of products (in the basket)m and the second the number of prod in stock.

Comment: If you want to use `$content->number` then just do that.

Comment: i am using it. $content->number must be the currently selected value. and stock the maximum that can be selected..

Comment: Then I don't understand why you have `$content->product_type->stock_2` in your code. If you want to select the option with value `$content->number`, then it's `$content->number` that should be in the loop. What am I missing here?

Comment: the content number can be 2 and the stock 3. i want to give the possibility to the user to choose as much as the stock is available.

Comment: @dana These details don't mean anything to me and can be abstracted away from the question. We just need to know how this loop is not what you want.